# How can I make confusion matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, confusion-matrix

Here, I have already build a detector `.xml` file by `SVM` with `HOG` features to detect human face with two classes (face and notFace). Now I want to evaluate the performance by confusion matrix. I have train samples of 2 classes. As a test sample, I want to use a picture which contains few faces. Are there any way in `Matlab` to evaluate the performance of this .xml detector file using these data?

Comment: Could this help? https://mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/confusion.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I am not understanding how to create S by Q matrices for `targets` and `outputs`?